# Dynamic data output from PHP script using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic, flush

guys! I need to output the result of PHP script dynamically onto another page via AJAX request(s) (if it is possible).

**More deatails**:

I`m parsing data from remote API of car manufacturers and models database and need to correctly parse it into my local Opencart 2.3 DB. As it is about 150K modifications of cars out there, I need to see on what stage is parsing process now.

So, what I have now 
1. I have a page where we can start parsing process:
[image: Parser interface]

And the entire its code (you can see AJAX calling script in the bottom):

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_form; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <?php echo $text_input; ?><button class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $text_parse; ?></button>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-meta-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $text_below; ?></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea rows="25" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <?php // echo $text_success; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>

<script>
    $('body').on('click', '.btn.btn-primary', function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        var url = window.location.href;
        var urlAux = url.split('=');
        var token = urlAux[2];
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/category_parser/parser&token='+token,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                    $('textarea.form-control').append(response);
                $('.btn.btn-primary').attr("disabled", false);
                },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('Something went wrong');
                $('.btn.btn-primary').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

2. THe AJAX fires to PHP method which begins to parse and to return some data:

can't copy the code ;( It's too much for Stack...
But imagine that we have simple cycle:

```
 if (ob_get_level() == 0) {
                    ob_start();
                }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        echo "bla-";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
ob_end_flush();
```

So, we need to output it into text area of the page where we want to have results of the script work. Something like that:
[image: bl-blablabla]

And I already has that result. But all the "bla-bla-bla" (for example) appears not one by one in one second, but after the script ends working in 5 second and outputs all the result.

How can I output the data from PHP script dynamically and is it possible by using AJAX at all? I have no strict conditions of what technology to use, it should work somehow and that's all. If it will be iframe or something else, it would be great anyway. Asking for help as I'm quite stuck at the moment.

Thanks to everybody!

Comment: unfortunately buffer flushing and ajax don't work very well together. From what I've read previously (and you can google the same material) it's very tricky to get it working. I would have a search around and see if you can make it work. If the remote API supports paging of the response, that might be a better road to go down. Then you just make repeated ajax requests to the server at intervals, requesting the next page each time, until you get to the end.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is all the stuff I found on Internet says it will be a tough fight with ajax. But i'll try to find some solution. After all, there are tonns of plugins and online services that provides progress bars and dynamic process information of what is happening at the server. The problem is I have no idea how they are working :)